# Tikz: Problem using "of" on subsequent Beamer frames

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, errors

Compiling this MWE yields the desired result: a beamer frame with two nodes positioned relative to each other.

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm and 5mm]
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\node (inc) [label=above:Incumbent] {};
\node (ent)   [below left=25mm of inc,label=left:Entrant] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The following code, which includes a second copy of *exactly the same frame*, however, causes PDFLaTeX to throw up the error `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator`o' or `of' (in '25mm of inc').`

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm and 5mm]
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\node (inc) [label=above:Incumbent] {};
\node (ent)   [below left=25mm of inc,label=left:Entrant] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm and 5mm]
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\node (inc) [label=above:Incumbent] {};
\node (ent)   [below left=25mm of inc,label=left:Entrant] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know why this happens, and how I can have multiple slides using the `of` positioning command in my presentation?

Comment: The `\usetikzlibrary` part should go into the preamble and not been executed twice. It loads an external package that may well define global symbols, hence the clash.

Comment: I have added this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Load packages and libraries only in the preamble!**

The issue is caused by the `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` inside the `frame` environment.

Generally, packages in LaTeX are intended to be loaded only inside the preamble of the document. Many of them introduce global elements, add to document-specific hooks, or use other features that may lead to unwanted side effects if loaded inside a scope or behind `\begin{document}`. This holds for `\usepackage`, but also for most package-specific extension mechanisms, such as `\usetikzlibrary`.

The following compiles without any problems:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}  % Always load TikZ libraries in the preamble!
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm and 5mm]
  \node (inc) [label=above:Incumbent] {};
  \node (ent)   [below left=25mm of inc,label=left:Entrant] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm and 5mm]
  \node (inc) [label=above:Incumbent] {};
  \node (ent)   [below left=25mm of inc,label=left:Entrant] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```